# Matplotlib live graph update issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a program that receives sensor data through the serial port of my laptop and then prints these values to a screen with a Tkinter gui and adds these values to an array for my matplotlib live graphs. The program works fine for a while but once it gets to the `.pop(0)` section, I get this error:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, have shapes (5000,) and (5001,)

and no graph data shows when I click my Tkinter button.

[image]

I have changed this section `if(cntB2>10000):` to `if(cntB2=>10000):`      but still no luck.

This is a stripped down version of my script. This will not work if you run it as all the Tkinter labels and placement take a lot of codeing and make it difficult to analyse the problem.

```
import matplotlib


# Main Tkinter application
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
            Frame.__init__(self, master)
            root.title( "Stylibleue Dashboard")
            root.state('zoomed')
            root.configure(background='black')

            self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")      # Thus makes an invisible grid to make the layout
            self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=3)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
            self.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)



    def createWidgets(self):

            #B1 Labels --------------------------
            self.temperature = Label(self, text="Bassin 1", font=('Verdana', 15), fg="red", bg="black").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="nsew")


################ This is the Graph page when button is clicked 

    def button_press2(self):
            clicked = True
            print (clicked)
            drawnow(self.makeFig2)                         #Call drawnow to update our live graph
            plt.pause(.000001)                             #Pause Briefly. Important to keep drawnow from crashing
    def makeFig2(self):
        mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
        mng.window.state('zoomed')
        plt.title("D.O graph bassin 2")                    #Plot the title
        plt.grid(True)                                     #Turn the grid on
        plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=30, ha='right') #ha is the same as horizontalalignment
        plt.ylabel('D.O')                                  #Set ylabels
        plt.plot(dt2,Oxy2, label='D.O')                     #plot the temperature
        plt.legend(loc='upper left')                       #plot the legend
        plt.draw()


##########  This takes the sensor reading 

    def measure(self):
        if com_port_connected == True:    
            try:                    
                # If there is incoming data to parse and display it
                if(arduinoData.inWaiting()>0 ):    #and arduinoData.inWaiting()>50 ):
                    arduinoString = arduinoData.readline()
                    self.B10.set("")
                    arduinoString =str(arduinoString)                                   #removes the surrounding rubbish
                    aaa = arduinoString.split(',')
                    a = sys.getsizeof(arduinoString) 

                    print("-------Received Sensor data-------")
                    print(a)


                    self.B10.set("")
                    arduinoString =str(arduinoString)                                   #removes the surrounding rubbish
                    aaa = arduinoString.split(',')
                    print(arduinoString.split(','))
                    a = sys.getsizeof(arduinoString) 


####################  This updates the GUI labels and adds to the graph array   


                    if aaa[1] == "B2" and Preceed == True:#BASSIN TWO ADDRESS HERE 

                            self.B2.set(str(aaa[3]))
                            self.B22.set(str(aaa[5]))
                            self.B22222.set(str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m %H:%M")))
                            print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m %H:%M"))#%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S



                            try:
                                tempF2.append(float(aaa[5]))
                                Oxy2.append(float(aaa[3]))
                                dt2.append(datetime.datetime.now())

                                global cntB2
                                cntB2=cntB2+1

                                print("cntB2")
                                print(cntB2)

                                if(cntB2>10000):
                                    tempF2.pop(0)
                                    Oxy2.pop(0)
                                    dt2.pop(0)
                            except:
                                print("Error could not append sensor data")



            except:
                print("No data received")
                self.B10.set("Connect RX")


            self.after(1000,self.measure)                       # Wait 1 second between each measurement
            self.after(1000,self.check_buttons)                 # check for button press 
            arduinoData.flushOutput()
            arduinoData.flushInput()


# Create and run the GUI
root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you include the plotting code?

Comment: Plotting code added.

Comment: Are you running this all in one thread? Or separate threads for plotting and sensor read in?

Comment: All in one thread.

Comment: I realize you can’t post the entire code on SO but do you have it on GitHub or something you could provide a link to? From the code you’ve shown here there is nothing that explains the behavior as far as I can see....

Comment: Hi William I just amended the post to try and make it clearer.

Comment: Is there anywhere else in the code where `Oxy2` is modified? Also how is `Oxy2` declared?

Comment: That is helpful... which lines gives the valueerror?

Comment: I have added a picture of the error message above and also updated the github page so it is the full code now. Hopfully that makes it easier to anaylise.

Comment: You may want to try implementing `DO1`, `dt1`, etc as queues using [`collection.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) as outlined [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-queues).... no guarantee that it will work but I expect it to more reliably work than basic lists

Comment: Hi william, thanks Ill give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try that suggestion yet?